# Switch on an ATX power supply with Raspberry Pi 3B (ATX no for Raspberry Pi power supply)

Tags: switches

My advice request is regarding an arcade machine. Now I have it running with a Dell desktop. However I want to switch to Raspberry Pi as I'm tired of managing all the emulators and realized that using Retropie software is more simple.

My Arcade have some 5V LED lights buttons, a 10 x 12V LED lights marquee and a 180W amplifier with 2 x 60W speakers connected to an ATX Power supplier. I don't want to power my Raspberry Pi 3B from the ATX power supplier as I read that this would generate noise in the amplifier (my current Dell is doing this at the moment).

So my idea is powering my Raspberry pi 3B from an official 2.5 amp 5.1V power supplier. I've got a nice switch button for starting the raspberry Pi 3B.

What I really want to do is setting the arcade so that when I switch on the Raspberry Po 3B this will switch on the ATX power supply so all the arcade lights and the amplifier are supplied by it.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: A simple relay circuit connected to the GPIO and script that runs on startup should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [connect pin 14 of the ATX supply to ground (e.g. pin 3)](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/convert-atx-psu-to-bench-supply.html) for it to come on.

You could do this with a simple transistor, but I'd use an opto-isolator as you're worried about coupling noise (also in case you misconnect the ATX end). See for example [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5342/36740).  You can get them to run directly off 3.3V, or that need an external resistor.